# Issues within a function getting 'variable undefined' error

Tags: javascript

A few years back I wrote a javascript library for a simple task. Today I had to visit it again, and I am not happy with my code. If it would just run... I know it ran back then but now I have no clue why it doesn't.

I call the function `fixPersonnummer` with the values it needs and then it crashes, saying that the variable `fixedPersonnummer` isn't defined. I tried to add var and let but that makes the result become whatever int I give the var.
What have I done wrong?

```
function fixPersonnummer(personnummer, svarsLangd) {
    var len = personnummer.length;

    if (len === 13 && parseInt(svarsLangd) === 10) {
        removeStreck = removeDash(personnummer);
        fixedPersonnummer = removeCentuary(removeStreck);
    }
...
```

Comment: please add some examples and the wanted result of it.

Comment: fixedPersonnummer vs. fixPersonnummer (note the "ed" in the first case)

Comment: Declare: `let fixedPersonnummer = removeCentuary(removeStreck)`

Comment: To me it looks like fixedPersonnummer and removeStreck were global variables. Most likely there is more code missing than you think.

Comment: That did not work with let on the variable. Would it help to make them global vars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In this code example `removeStreck` and `fixedPersonnummer` not initialized. Try to initialie this variables first.

Comment: Basic error requires a basic solution. Thanks @petia !